# Constructing a simple linear system using `scipy.sparse`

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Imagine a simple 3x3 matrix upon which I impose the following "boundary conditions". Here are an array showing the corresponding indexes if flattened, and the boundary value.

```
I =     B = 
0 3 6   3 0 1
1 4 7   3 0 1
2 5 8   3 0 1
```

It is easy to see that the flattened boundary value array would be

```
b = 
3 3 3 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

I also have a connectivity structure C, given as a set of pairs,

```
C = 
0 0 1 1 2 3 3 4 4 5 6 7
1 3 2 4 5 4 6 5 7 8 6 8
```

I wanna construct a matrix A that represents this linear system, to use `spsolve(A, b)` and get

```
A =
 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
 1  0  0 -3  1  0  1  0  0
 0  1  0  1 -4  1  0  1  0
 0  0  1  0  1 -3  0  0  1
 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1

x = 
3 3 3 2 2 2 1 1 1
```

This was very simple to do using numpy and manipulating dense matrices, zeroing out columns, and so on. However as the matrices grow large, I start running out of memory and the solvers are incredibly slow.

I thought I'd build my sparse matrix with this logic:

1. Initialize a matrix using the connectivity array and `np.ones_like` one of the vectors
2. Add the matrix and its transpose to fill out the LD region
3. *where `b` is nonzero*: Wipe out the rows and place a 1 in the diagonal (this represents an initial condition)
4. *where `b` is zero*: Sum the matrices along `axis=1`, and place the negative value of the sum into each diagonal (this balances out sinks and sources)

This works perfectly in `numpy`, but I find it absolutely impossible to do anything useful with the `sparse` matrices after initializing them. They don't handle item deletion, transpose, etc. Can I get a walk through on these operations?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'm going with this so far

Seems a little obscure, like I'm doing something wrong

```
b = np.array([3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
i = (0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7)
j = (1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8, 7, 8)

f = b!=0
A = sparse.lil_matrix((b.size, b.size))
A[f,f] = 1
C = sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones_like(i+j), (i+j,j+i)), shape=(b.size, b.size)).tolil()
D = sparse.diags(np.asarray(C.sum(axis=1).T)[0], 0).tocsr()
A[~f,:] = C[~f, :] - D[~f]

print A.toarray()
```

Comment: I did! I will write it up today.